# QGIS- Fixing adjacent lines that looks like touching each other but do not

Tags: qgis, line

I'm trying to dissolve and then multipart to single part a line layer. The thing is that after I'm breaking it to single part some lines that look like touching each other break back to little parts. I was thinking maybe they are not really touching each other.

How can I check if they are really touching and, if they are not, how can I fix it?

Comment: What software are you trying to do this with? One way to do this with ArcGIS would be to [clean](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/clean.htm) the coverage with an appropriate fuzzy tolerance. I think you could do something similar in [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html) with ST_Snap.

Comment: Can you add more details about what you want to happen to the lines that aren't touching each other?  Do you want to snap them together?  Dissolve them?  V.clean, a function in the GRASS QGIS plugin may do what you want.